# Programmatically create links

Tags: 8

I need to tag keywords through the body which will display as links.

Let's say in the middle of the text I want to tag *job listing*. When the page is displayed, it would look like `http://urlprefix&keyword1+keyword2&urlappendix`, where *urlprefix* and *urlappendix* is hardcoded in the module.

How do I build a custom shortcode for the Shortcode module?

Comment: If you are trying to alter outgoing links by a fixed ruleset, you might consider the [OutboundPathProcessor](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!PathProcessor!OutboundPathProcessorInterface.php/function/OutboundPathProcessorInterface%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.2.x). There are multiple questions with code examples here on SE. AFAIK this does work on _all_ internal links (even inside CKeditor), but not for exteral links though.

Comment: I am not trying to process all outgoing links. Only certain keyword that will be tagged while the user creates the content.